# Filter column based on several rows in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table, `test_result`, that has a foreign key, `test_run_id`, to another table called `test_run`. I want to find all rows in test_result that reference certain rows in test_run.

I have tried using arrays. For example by doing: `select array(select id from test_run)` I get:

```
 array
-------
 {1,2}
(1 row)
```

Using this array in a `with` clause I then tried to filter using `where` and `any`:

`with test_runs as (select array(select id from test_run)) select * from test_result where test_run_id = any(test_runs);`

which returns `ERROR:  column "test_runs" does not exist`. I know that an array literal can be filtered in an `any` statement but from this I take that a predefined array cannot? Or is it the syntax that is incorrect?

Open to other suggestions if using an array is not the correct way to go about it. Maybe there is a way to use the rows directly without converting to an array?

Comment: Use `test_run_id in (select tr.id from test_run tr)`. Or just `JOIN` two tables (because parent table is a source of FK, it will not multiply rows of the child table)

Comment: It is part of a bigger expression with later joins so I think your first suggestion using `in` works well in this scenario. Thanks!